# Whats wrong with my open cl kernel?

Tags: opencl

The code is multiplication of a sparse matrix stored in compressed column storage with a column vector.First is serial code.Second is open cl kernel.let me use more meaningful names instead of inputimage and output.

I had to parallelize my code.The serial output is different than the kernel's output.Can somebody please tell me anything I am missing?

The serial code was

```
int result[4]={0,0,0,0};
   for(int col=0;col<4;col++)
     {
         for(int j=rowptr[col];j<rowptr[col+1];j++)
         {

         result[index[j]]+=val[j]*colvector[col];

         }
     }
```

Its output is different from the parallel code.The work units per kernel is set to 4
The parallel code is given below.Somebody please tell me what i am missing.

```
      int col=get_global_id(0);

  for(int j=rowptr[col];j<rowptr[col+1];j++)
         {

         result[index[j]]+=val[j]*colvector[col];

         }
```

Comment: How are you invoking the kernel?  Perhaps you have a mistake which is causing a different number of threads to be executed than you expect.  Also, what data types are the different inputImage arrays?

Comment: All datta types are integers.If you look closely you would see that this is actually the serial and parallel versions of the code to multiply a sparse matrix in compressed column format with a column vector.

Comment: no i only need 4 threads to execute.Each thread executing a different iteration fo the loop.Eric Bainville's answer is corect about race condition problem.Th problem is how do i use locks to keep this code parallel but get the same results on both serial and parallel code.

Comment: A few Qs for you: How large is rowptr usually? why only 4 threads? what does index[j] represent?

Answer (score 3):

In OpenCL, the 4 work items will be executed in parallel. They all will try to update `output2[inputImage4[j]]` at the same time. The behavior is undefined, but what you will probably observe is the contribution of only one of the 4 work items.

Solving this kind of issues requires a modification of the algorithm, or the use of atomic operations (which will serialize the updates) if you don't access the value too often.

Comment: this depends on the value of `inputImage4[j]`, doesn't it?  You are right about the concurrent read/write problem in either case.

Comment: Can you suggest some modification to my kenel?The purpose of my code was to make the sparse matrix multiplication a parallel one.but if use locks it would become a serial code again.What do i do?